# THREECSG does not appear to work in my threejs program

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do a simple subtraction of two meshes that are (supposedly) generated in CSG and then I convert them to threejs mesh, create an object with mesh from that geometry. But when I try to put it on the screen nothing shows up. I checked my libraries by running known to work CSG test programs so that appears to be fine.

So I must be missing something along the way. Here is a link to a listing of the entire short program. If you see I am missing any crucial code I would really appreciate knowing what it is as I'm baffled.

thanks for anything you can tell me.

```
<script src="lightgl.js"></script>
<script src='vendor/three.js/build/three.min.js'></script>
<script src='vendor/three.js/build/stats.min.js'></script>
    <script src="vendor/csg.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/ThreeCSG.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black">
<script>

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 

1, 500);
    camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);
    camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

////////////////// This is the CSG code/////////////////////
var CSGsphere =CSG.sphere({radius: 1.3 });
CSGsphere.setColor(1, 0, 0);
var CSGcube= CSG.cube({center: [1,1,1]});
CSGcube.setColor(0,1, 0);
var  combined = CSGsphere.subtract(CSGcube);
var resultGeo= THREE.CSG.fromCSG( combined );
var meshobject = new THREE.Mesh( resultGEO,new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()); 
scene.add(meshobject);

renderer.render(scene, camera);

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running an outdated version of ThreeCSG, the syntax has changed and `THREE.CSG.fromCSG()` is no more.

I copied whats needed from the old source, cleared all Errors to make them run with three.js r71, but the returned geometry is not a legit `THREE.geometry`.

I would have added this as a comment, but I dont have enough reputation.